# Why does traversing when you send a pointer to pointer change the linklist permanently but pointer alone doesnt

Tags: c++, list, pointers

Okay, so basically for the code to print a linklist when I send NODE* HEAD as the argument it doesn't traverse the list for good like if I call the function twice it'll print the whole linklist both times BUT if I send NODE** HEAD and call print twice then the second time it will print NULL because it permanently traversed, why?

It got more confusing because if I try to add an element at the end of the linklist with node* head as argument it permanently adds it to the list. Why is node** head not a requirement in this case, adding code for this too.

I've looked it up a whole lot but I really couldn't figure out much.

```
void print(node * head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        cout<<head->data<<"-->";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
}
void inserstAtLAst(node * head,int data){
    node * temp = new node(data);
    while(head->next!=NULL){
        head = head->next;
    }
    head->next = temp;
}
```

Comment: If you rewrite `print` to accept a `node**` and call it as `print(&head_node)`, all writes to `*head` inside the function will change the value of `head_node`. You can convince yourself of this by printing the value of `head_node` and `&head_node` outside the function, printing `*head` and `head` inside the function, and noticing that they are the same.

Comment: I understand what happens but not why, that's where I'm lost.

Comment: Maybe visualising the list and the pointers in it will help you? Make a small list of three elements in code. Print the addresses of the nodes. Observe that the value of `head->next` is equal to the address of the next node. Simulate the `print` function as above, where you move the `head` pointer to different nodes.

Comment: Now do the same for the `print(node**)` case. Notice that you need an explicit `node*` box outside of the list, now. Walk through the list again and notice that you end up with a different value for the box.

Comment: That does help, thank you!